# How do I implement flowtype.js within my Drupal page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drupal-7

I'm getting this error trying to implement flowtype.js on my drupal page:

```
   TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('body').flowtype({
   minimum   : 100,
   maximum   : 1200,
   minFont   : 8,
   maxFont   : 60,
   fontRatio : 30
})')
    (anonymous function) (line 300)
    global code (line 309)
```

Here is the current call towards the bottom of the page:

```
<script >
jQuery(function($){
    $('body').flowtype({
       minimum   : 100,
       maximum   : 1200,
       minFont   : 8,
       maxFont   : 60,
       fontRatio : 30
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I'm not sure how to go further with this error message in order to reveal the core issue and come up with a fix. Thanks

Comment: Have you included the plugin? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6960/how-to-add-jquery-plugin-to-drupal